# Symfony REST: voryx/restgeneratorbundle Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content

Tags: php, json, rest, symfony, composer-php

Today, I decided to learn and task myself to create REST API in Symfony2.
I have installed composer using this command

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Now I am installing Voryx REST Generator Bundle using this command

```
php composer.phar require voryx/restgeneratorbundle dev-master
```

And I am getting this error

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of package

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for voryx/restgeneratorbundle dev-master -> s
le by voryx/restgeneratorbundle[dev-master].
    - voryx/restgeneratorbundle dev-master requires sensio/generator-bun
 -> satisfiable by sensio/generator-bundle[3.0.x-dev, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3
.0.3, v3.0.4, v3.0.5, v3.0.6] but these conflict with your requirements
um-stability
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

This is the github repository for the bundle

```
https://github.com/voryx/restgeneratorbundle
```

========EDITTED========
This is the composer.json file

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.5.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.5-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Please what am doing wrong?

Comment: do you start from  a composer.json files or you launch the commands in an initially empty dir?

Comment: I launched it in a directory that has symfony project that I created with netbeans

Comment: so the problem is about the dependency with your current configuration. Can you post your composer.json files?

Comment: PS: in a fresh sf3 installation this bundle works fine...

Comment: Please where can I download sf3

Comment: Please take a look I added composer.json file

Comment: I am using netbeans 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't specify the version of the bundle (dev-master) you want to install: simply let the job to Composer simply launch the command:

```
php composer.phar require voryx/restgeneratorbundle
```

And will install the version suitable with your current dependency (0.3.0).

For install a sf3 installation version please refer to the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) here: currently exists various way to install it. With composer you can simply run the command:

```
php composer.phar create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition my_project_name
```

Hope this help

Comment: I want the world to know that you are a genius. Thanks